# Who to use pass args to to python argparse in docker compose

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

I'm building a web crawler with selenium and I want to deploy it with selenium. Crawler is composed of two part, a chromedriver instance running in one container and my code who connect to running instance to process data. After trying to find a way to pass args to my code container via docker compose, I finally choose to just put var in .env file at build statement and use they are env vars in my program. So my python command to run crawler in dev is `python -m mcrawler --use-env-vars` . But when I use it in docker file, it seems --use-env-vars does not havec effect. This is my code in **main**.py and in Dockerfile. Thanks in advance if someone can help me. [Image of **main**.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjRSj.png), [Image of Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lurFX.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the code and not screen shots of it?